# Transform string[] to typed map of string to Symbol

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm looking to write a generic function that takes an array of strings and returns an object with keys from the values of that array and values equal to `Symbol.for()` that value.

Crucially, I want the resulting object to be typed, so the compiler knows what keys the resulting object has.

```js
function makeSymbolMap(keys: string[]):{ [key: string]: Symbol } {
  let results: { [key: string]: Symbol } = {};
  for (const value of keys) {
    results[value] = Symbol.for(value);
  }
  return results;
}

// symbolMap will have type {[p: string]: Symbol}, not { foo: Symbol, bar: Symbol }
const symbolMap = makeSymbolMap([ 'foo', 'bar' ]);
typeof symbolMap.foo === "symbol"; // the compiler doesn't know if symbolMap.foo exists or not
typeof symbolMap.bar === "symbol";
```

If typescript had a `valueOf` type operator, this is how it would look:

```js
function makeSymbolMap(keys: string[]):{ [key: valueOf keys]: Symbol } {
  let results: { [key: valueOf keys]: Symbol } = {};
  for (const value of keys) {
    results[value] = Symbol.for(value);
  }
  return results;
}
```

Comment: You should be using the type named `symbol` instead of `Symbol`, see [the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object).

Comment: Use generics: https://tsplay.dev/m0YKDW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update: Simplified based off @jcalz comment*

```
function makeSymbolMap<T extends string>(keys: T[]) {
  let results = {} as Record<T, symbol>;
  for (const value of keys) {
    results[value] = Symbol.for(value);
  }
  return results;
}
```

`symbolMap` will now have type completion.

Comment: `ArrayElement<typeof keys>` is just `T`, so there's no reason to use `ArrayElement`.

Comment: Use `symbol` instead of `Symbol`